# What does Stack Overflow use for its community wiki edits comparison feature?

Tags: support, stack-exchange, diff, technology

I am referring to this feature:

[image: Stack Overflow version control feature]

Note how Stack Overflow shows which bits have been deleted, and which parts have been added (shown in red and green).

Basically, I was wondering if Stack Overflow used an external piece of software for this capability. If they did not, could I know how they implemented such a thing (and how I could implement it in PHP)?

The main reason I think this is a plugin / external piece of software is because I was reading a post stating that the Stack Overflow live preview editor was made using WMD Markdown Editor.

Comment: It may have changed since 2009, but the implementation was described in [this Coding Horror blog post](https://blog.codinghorror.com/mixing-oil-and-water-authorship-in-a-wiki-world/).

Comment: There are many programs and libraries for diffing. “diff” on your favourite search engine. `diff` is also a common utility.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[Per balpha](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127497/suggested-edit-diff-shows-different-results-depending-upon-mode/128705#128705), Stack Exchange uses an in-house diff engine based on [a particular implementation](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11454/A-word-wise-HTML-text-compare-and-merge-engine) of [Eugene Myers' O(ND) difference algorithm](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11454/A-word-wise-HTML-text-compare-and-merge-engine), with several enhancements to support more natural diffing.

For brevity, I'll refer you to his [fairly detailed post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127497/suggested-edit-diff-shows-different-results-depending-upon-mode/128705#128705) for an indepth overview.